# Dynamically added panels always getting index as 0

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I an trying to dynamically add panels to an existing model binded list of panels(panel-group).
Index of a particular panel indicates at which position the panel in the list.
However the dynamically added panels in the list are always having index of the added panel as 0.

```html
for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListofItem.Count; i++)
{
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.List[i].item, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
  </div>
}
```

Suppose the list contains 10 panels then if i add a panel (cloning and appending)then the index of the panel added should be 10, but it is always 0.Why i am not able to get the index of client side added panels? and how do i get them?

Comment: Where is the code to determine the index of the elements?

Comment: .index() shall give the index of any panel.I am adding a class say 'Panelx' to the panel i am dynamically creating.therefore in that case,index will be obtained as $('.Panelx').index()

Answer (score 0):

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the **first element** within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

lets break `$('.Panelx').index()` down a bit

`$('.Panelx')` will return a list of panels with class `Panelx`. `.index()` will return the postion of the **first element** relative to the list. since the first element in the list is just the element with index 0. Its relative position will be 0 as well and thats why you are getting 0 back. Working as intended.

Comment: what should i do then to obtain the index relative to the list?I mean relative to the main list in which i am appending

Comment: @user5772245 get a list, enumerate thru it until you find the element you want and return the current index?